# Can a slab with a set of IR torches on it help to prevent blossom freeze in early spring?

Tags: diffraction, experimental-technique, infrared-radiation

Every year there are lot's of problems with blossom freeze caused by sudden drop in temperature of the envirement and cold winds. Can a set of parallel  infrared torches have a low drop of intensity of emitted IR-photons along a path of let say 200 meters so it can save several trees from freezing their blooms in spring. Every torch may have a very small frontal semicircular mirror that forces the rays that would be just emitted radially in the space to reach the parabolic mirror on te rear part of the emitter where they meet the other half part of photons and together become parallel when reflected from the parabolic mirror. I think  the only thing that would attenuate the density of these photons is diffraction. [image]

Comment: For the downvote...... https://youtu.be/OdmY17A1s9I.... 6:28

Answer (score 1):

It takes quite a bit of energy to heat an orchard and prevent freezing. The conventional way of combating this effect is with *smudge pots* and *wind machines*. A smudge pot is a portable heater that burns fuel oil; when freezing conditions are expected, the orchard operator places a large number of smudge pots among the trees and lights them.

The wind machine is an aircraft or automobile engine (or sometimes an electric motor) spinning a propeller on the top of a tall pole. This stirs the air blanketing the ground and the trees and prevents freezing air from settling in within the "boundary layer" that encloses the foliage. One wind machine can cover a large parcel of land and delay the onset of frost damage within it.